# User defined class import at run time

Tags: java, compilation

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve the following use case:

- A user can define a Java class, say `MyFoo` like this (the code is generated automatically and the guid is set to avoid name collisions)

```
import com.bar.entities.BaseEntity;
package com.bar.entities.defined.79B35635_DEDF_A344_9621_0477A6E71725;

public class MyFoo extends BaseEntity {

    public String getFoo() { ... }
    public Integer getBar() { ... }

    @Override 
    public byte[] serialize() {...}
}
```

- A user can import that Java class in other class like this:

```
package com.bar.business;

import com.bar.entities.defined.79B35635_DEDF_A344_9621_0477A6E71725.MyFoo;

public class Business extends Minion {
    @Override
    public void execute(EntityProvider ep) {
        MyFoo myFoo = ep.get("myFoo", MyFoo.class);
        if (myFoo.getBar() < 10)  {
            notifyMaster();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionaly I have a Java application (actually a Grizzly HTTP Server with a Jersey API Rest) that must be able to compile both classes.

¿How can I compile both classes? The first one can be compiled. The second one can't because the compiler says that the method `getBar()` is not known (it does not fail at the import line, surpringsly)

I want to send both `Class<?>` instances over the network and use them elsewhere via reflection with `getDeclaredConstructor()`

Kind regards.

Comment: Well in this instance, if `MyFoo` can't be imported, then `BaseEntity` must be.  You have to import the base class/interface or nothing will work.

Comment: `I want to send both Class<?> instances over the network` You will still need to have the class definitions (the .class file or .jar file) available to the client or it won't be able to read the instance data from the network.

Comment: Fixed typo. Indeed i will send that `.class file` (actually as a byte array). However I can't generate the second `.class` (for the `Minion` class)

Comment: It feels like something is messed up in your environment (in other words nothing to do with Java).  If you can import a `MyFoo` but can't call a method on it, then that's really wrong.  Perhaps you have an old file still on your hard disk (and on your compiler class path) that's fulfilling the `import` but doesn't have the right definitions?  Do a full clean, and check your build file and default paths carefully.